# bootstrap table polling updates from MySQL with continuous data

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, twitter-bootstrap

I am using bootstrap table to represent data stored in MySQL (with new data pouring into DB every second) and have the following snippet in a separate PHP file to query them and present it on a front UI:

```
Query.php

$sql = 'SELECT * FROM table WHERE date = (SELECT MAX(date) FROM table) LIMIT 5;'
while ($row = $result1->fetch_assoc())
{
    $str='<tr><td>' . $row['ID'] . '</td>';
    $str1='<td>' . $row['keyword'] . '</tr></td>';
    echo $str;
    echo $str1;
}
```

On the front-end, I have a short JS to make a poll to the DB every second:

```
index.php
<div class="panel-body">
 <div>
  <table class="table table-inverse table-striped table-bordered">
   <thead>
    <th>ID</th>
    <th>Keyword</th>
   </thead>
    <tbody id="display" >
    </tbody>
  </table>
  </div>

  //other html code
    $(document).ready(function() {
        setInterval(function() {
            $.post('query.php', function(data) {
                $('#display').prepend(data);
            });
        }, 1000);
    });
```

Its working fine as to querying data every second and showing it and appending the data. However, I would like to have the append action on the table. For instance, 10 rows limit and update every second and removing the earliest row.

One good example of what I am looking at achieving: 
https://blockchain.info/      (under the "latest transaction" column)

Comment: Use **ajax** to get new data, and use **javascript** to update the table

Comment: thanks @weigreen, but how about the portion to dynamically update a pre-set number of rows instead of refreshing the entire table?

Comment: using javascript you can do many things, include you wanted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

declare a height for your table. In ajax use `prepend()` function to merge your latest record to top of your table. Hope you understand what i'm saying. If you need a help I'm happy to guide you

Comment: Hi Fairy Dancer, thanks for providing some directions for me to work on. Yes, I roughly get what you mean as I am not well-verse with Ajax/JS. I will try and update you here should I encounter any problems. thanks and appreciate your help.

Comment: Hi Fairy Dancer, i am seeing some progression here. But I cant seems to limit the row height. I attempt to change the query to only poll 5 results, but cant get the appending action. looking forward to your advice if your online. thank you.

Comment: you have to create ajax code to retrieve data from the database. then only it will append to your record.

Comment: hi Fairy Dance. Thanks again. Got the appending to work using the above snippet. However, I am stuck now trying to populate just 10 rows. I am thinking about querying a fix set (10 rows) and pass it to an array which will be shown on the html table. After which I will do another query to get the updated data and update the array.

Comment: Exactly buddy. give limit to your sql query and order by descending. so it fetch latest 10 record when page load and ajax retrieve also updated record of 10 only so it will work fine for you.

Comment: Hi Fairy dance, appreciate your kind advice. I got it working based on your  steps. Thanks again! cheers!